# difference between Spring mvc redirect and general jsp name return

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Please consider these code snippets

```
   protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:DummyRedirectPage.htm");

}
```

and

```
       protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    return new ModelAndView("somejsp");

}
```

Can anyone tell me the difference between the two? In both the cases the handler method is navigating the flow to a view page.

Comment: `redirect:` prefixes are handled by `UrlBasedViewResolver`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the first one user will receive HTTP 302 response to redirect into DummyRedirectPage.htm. If the handler was mapped to a POST method, this will force user to perform GET to DummryRedierctPage.htm

On the second one your view resolver will resolve `"somejsp"` into an actual view. No HTTP 302 response is given to user.

Please read about [PRG (Post Redirect Get) design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) to find out why this matters.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So that means redirect is just to convert from POST to a GET request?

Comment: That's just small part of it. When user issue a new GET request all the data on your model might / not lost. `redirect:` syntax is useful in a POST-REDIRECT-GET pattern: en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get